# Finding all the elements that have a specific order

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm trying to understand how to find all of the elements of a given order. For example, I have the following group: $\mathbb{Z}_{10}\times\mathbb{Z}_{12}$. How for example, to calculate all the elements which have order of $8$ or $6$? I could check every possible element in a group but it feels like the "hard" way. Is there a more sophisticated way?

Comment: Given groups $G$ and $H$, and $(a,b)\in G\times H$, do you know the relation between $|(a,b)|, |a|$ and $|b|$?

Comment: @Arthur are you talking about the $lcm$?

Answer (score 1):

The order of $(a,b)$ is the lcm of the order of $a$ and $b$. So, if you're looking for elements of order $8$ in $\mathbb Z/{10} \times \mathbb Z/{12}$, then the element $(a,b)$ must be such that $\text{lcm}(|a|, |b|) = 8$. You also have the further restriction $|a|$ must divide $10$ and $|b|$ must divide $12$. Can you proceed from here by yourself?

Comment: I understood everything you said. But can't seem to proceed from there. How does it help me to find all the elements?

Comment: You generate the list of elements $\{(a,b) \mid |a| \text{ divides } 10, |b| \text{ divides } 12\}$ and from that pick only the elements that also satisfy $\text{lcm}(|a|, |b|) = 8$.

Comment: Yes, I understand it. but should I follow each element one by one or is there a sophisticated way?