# Solving $lcm(|a|,|b|)=8$ when $|a|$ divides $10$ and $|b|$ divides $12$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I was trying to study about the $\times$ action when speaking about groups. My question is more a technical than theoretical.

I came across with a previous thread ([link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3208827/finding-all-the-elements-that-have-a-specific-order)) which tries to find the all of the elements of order $6$ and $8$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{10}\times\mathbb{Z}_{12}$. The answer in the thread suggests that the order of $(a,b)\in \mathbb{Z}_{10}\times\mathbb{Z}_{12}$ is $lcm(|a|,|b|)$ so if we want to find the elements of order $8$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{10}\times\mathbb{Z}_{12}$ then we need to solve $lcm(|a|,|b|)=8$ when $|a|$ divides $10$ and $|b|$ divides $12$.

But technically speaking, what is the right way to solve this equation?

Comment: I don’t think there are any solutions

Comment: why not? what about order $6$?

Comment: For order $6$, take $1$ or $2$ and $6$, or $2$ and $3$

Answer (score 1):

You factor the desired order into primes, then must have at least one of $a,b$ contribute the required number of prime factors.  For order $6=2 \times 3$, only $b$ can have a factor $3$, either $a$ or $b$ must be even, and neither can have a factor $4$.  This gives the pairs $(1,6),(2,6),(2,3)$ as solutions.

As neither $10$ nor $12$ has a factor $8=2^3$, no element of $\Bbb {Z_{10} \times Z_{12}}$ has order $8$.

Answer (score 1):

Factors of $10$ are $1,2,5$, and $10.$  Factors of $12$ are $1,2,3,4,6, $ and $12$.  If the least common multiple of $a$ and $b$ were $8$, then first of all $a$ and $b$ would have to divide $8$, so they would have to be $1,2,4,$ or $8$, and second of all both could not divide $4$, so one would have to be $8$, but $8$ is not a factor of $10$ or $12.$

Answer (score 1):

Take $g \in \mathbb{Z}_{10}\times\mathbb{Z}_{12}$.
Since $lcm(10,12)=60$, we have $60g=0$.
Therefore, the order of $g$ divides $60$ and so cannot be $8$.